# Get difference of dates within 2 input fields and display it on another field

Tags: javascript

I am noobie in javascript and has been having troubles implementing the right code for this topic. I already tried checking the existing forum questions within your site and others but I always end up with a broken code. Basically, I need for the DueInDays input text to display the difference between DueDate and AssignDate onChange of any of the 2 fields. Below is the last code I tried.

```js
function diffrenceindays() {
  var startdate = GetDateValue(AssignDate);
  var Enddate = GetDateValue(DueDate);

  var oneday = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
  var differenceInDays = ((Enddate - startdate) / oneday);
  if (differenceInDays < 0) {
    alert(" date cannot be less then start date");

  }
  alert(" diffrence in days  " + differenceInDays);

}

function GetDateValue(field) {


  var year = field.getFullYear();
  var month = field.getMonth();
  var day = field.getDate();
  dateOnly = new Date(year, month, day);
  return dateOnly;


}
```

```html
<form>
  <label>Due Date
    <input type="text" class="DatePicker" name="DueDate" id="DueDate" value="" size="32" onchange="diffrenceindays();" />
  </label>
  <label>Assign Date
    <input type="text" class="DatePicker" name="AssignDate" id="AssignDate" value="" size="32" onchange="diffrenceindays();" />
  </label>
  <label>Due in Days
    <input type="text" id="DueInDays" />
  </label>
</form>
```

Comment: well I do not see you setting the value of the input, just alerting the value. How does a text field act like a Date object?

Answer (score 0):

Start Date and End date  are Date objects. If you want to compare their relative times you should use the getTime method 
i.e.

```
function diffrenceInDays(date1,date2) {
      var startdate = date1.getTime();
      var enddate = date2.getTime();

      var oneday = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
      var differenceInDays = ((enddate - startdate) / oneday);
      if (differenceInDays < 0) {
        alert(" date cannot be less then start date");

      }
      alert(" diffrence in days  " + Math.floor(differenceInDays));
}
```

You should pass in the days to the function instead of finding them within the function.

You should also read epascarello's comment.